# How do I change the jhipster default ("/") page?

Tags: angular, jhipster

I created an angular 2 module and routed it successfully to "dashboard." I'd like to replace the default jHipster homepage with my module, but I can't seem to make it work. Is there something special about the home route or home component or route that I need to know about to swap them for a different module?

Parenthetically, I would like to use jHipster as he basis for my angular2/webpack/spring-boot app, but I am having trouble finding documentation on all the bells and whistles. A recommendation for a thorough reference (if there is one, wold be appreciated)

TIA!

Comment: JHipster documents only its specific parts, so all the standard parts are documented by underlying technologies (angular, spring boot, jpa, spring security, webpack)

Comment: For webpack, https://survivejs.com/webpack/introduction/

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you want to do it, JHipster generates code and then it's up to you to modify it.

- The simplest is to modify the generated files under `src/main/webapp/app/home` which defines `*HomeModule`. Then `yo jhipster:upgrade`command will do its best to keep your modifications using git merge when updating JHipster code to newer version.
- Alternatively, you can decide to keep generated `*HomeModule` unchanged, add a new one using same component selector and replace its reference to `*HomeModule` in `src/main/webapp/app/app.module.ts` to your new module.

Comment: I'm not sure how solution 1 or 2 works. I changed the home.route's path to 'home' and the dahboard.route's path to ''. That doesn't work. Can you elaborate? Can you elaborate on solution 2? app.module imports JHipster2HomeModule and my new DashboardModule. Where or when does app.module decide to use one over the other??

Comment: You don't need to change home route's path in both options because only one home module is active. In option 2, app.module should import only your DashboardModule, not JHipster2HomeModule.

Comment: Why should it matter if I redirect the module called "home" to a different path/route?

Comment: I'm just describing ways that do not require to modify routes and avoid component selector conflicts. I did not see enough of your code to pretend one way is better or not. Feel free to share more code.

Comment: I must be missing something, then. If I completely remove all app references to HomeModule (JHipsterHomeModule) I still don;t get the default page going to DashboardComponent. I notice that app.module bootstraps JhiMainComponent. Is there something in main/main.component.ts that I'm not understanding that is doing this?

Comment: main defines only the structure of the page and is used in index.html with `jhi-main`component selector. As long as you did not mess with component selectors in main or in home and did nto remove their related elements in HTML templates it should work.

Comment: have you found a solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're asking for? How does one modify the JHipster home page?

[image: My Home Page]

This wasn't "swapped out". I started modifying the JHipster app after generation. Gael has provided good answers but I think you're expecting an Angular lesson. The great feature that JHipster provides is a template for your application. It's up to you to modify it.

Comment: I suppose that will work and that's where I'm headed. I had thought that JHipster was abstracted out enough that I could just switch the routes, but I guess there's more to it than that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To redirect after login you should change login() in login.component.ts file.
Add

> this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);

```
        login () {
        this.loginService.login({
            username: this.username,
            password: this.password,
            rememberMe: this.rememberMe
        }).then(() => {
            this.authenticationError = false;
            this.activeModal.dismiss('login success');
            if (this.router.url === '/register' || this.router.url === '/activate' ||
                this.router.url === '/finishReset' || this.router.url === '/requestReset') {
                this.router.navigate(['']);
            }

            this.eventManager.broadcast({
                name: 'authenticationSuccess',
                content: 'Sending Authentication Success'
            });

            // // previousState was set in the authExpiredInterceptor before being redirected to login modal.
            // // since login is succesful, go to stored previousState and clear previousState
            let previousState = this.stateStorageService.getPreviousState();
            if (previousState) {
                this.stateStorageService.resetPreviousState();
                this.router.navigate([previousState.name], { queryParams:  previousState.params });
            }
            this.router.navigate(['dashboard']); // <-Add here
}).catch(() => {
            this.authenticationError = true;
        });
    }
```

I also have question, did you manage to put two entities component on dashboard?

Comment: I am actually interested in literally swapping out the homepage with my dashboard. Firstly even without a login. If I switch the routes so home.route.ts's path is 'home' and dashboard.route.ts's path is '' I would expect my new homepage to be the dashboard, but it's not. WRT your 2nd question. I'm still working on the basics and haven't tried to add functionality to the dashboard yet.

Comment: I also downvoted this b/c it's not answering my question of how to change the homepage. Good to know, though

Answer (score 0):

1st Identify the route path by searching for

**path: ''**

You will find it in the app/home/home.route.ts

add some characters of your choice to the empty string to put the Jhipster home component on a different URI path.

since it is set to an empty string it is what is displayed by default if no URI is specified.

2nd if you want to set a different component to the default you will need to create a new module ("dashboard.module"), component ("dashboard.component") and route ("dashboard.route") you can use the home component as a code reference.

In the new landing pages route (dashboard.route.ts) set an empty string as the path

**path: ''**

3rd register the module in the app.module and viola.